# Unable to get rid of 302 redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I have following in my htaccess file:

```
# Use the front controller as index file. It serves as a fallback solution when
# every other rewrite/redirect fails (e.g. in an aliased environment without
# mod_rewrite). Additionally, this reduces the matching process for the
# start page (path "/") because otherwise Apache will apply the rewriting rules
# to each configured DirectoryIndex file (e.g. index.php, index.html, index.pl).
DirectoryIndex app.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Determine the RewriteBase automatically and set it as environment variable.
    # If you are using Apache aliases to do mass virtual hosting or installed the
    # project in a subdirectory, the base path will be prepended to allow proper
    # resolution of the app.php file and to redirect to the correct URI. It will
    # work in environments without path prefix as well, providing a safe, one-size
    # fits all solution. But as you do not need it in this case, you can comment
    # the following 2 lines to eliminate the overhead.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]

    # Sets the HTTP_AUTHORIZATION header removed by apache
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect to URI without front controller to prevent duplicate content
    # (with and without `/app.php`). Only do this redirect on the initial
    # rewrite by Apache and not on subsequent cycles. Otherwise we would get an
    # endless redirect loop (request -> rewrite to front controller ->
    # redirect -> request -> ...).
    # So in case you get a "too many redirects" error or you always get redirected
    # to the start page because your Apache does not expose the REDIRECT_STATUS
    # environment variable, you have 2 choices:
    # - disable this feature by commenting the following 2 lines or
    # - use Apache >= 2.3.9 and replace all L flags by END flags and remove the
    #   following RewriteCond (best solution)
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^app\.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]

    # If the requested filename exists, simply serve it.
    # We only want to let Apache serve files and not directories.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule .? - [L]

    # Rewrite all other queries to the front controller.
    RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
        # the start page to the front controller explicitly so that the website
        # and the generated links can still be used.
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
        # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
    </IfModule>
```

Each time i enter in url just the domain name without www like example.com i see 302 redirect. How can i fix this?

I tried adding following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But above also did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @anubhava - Yes i tried clearing cache. If i just type example.com it causes 302.

Comment: @anubhava - No only if i type "example.com", if i type "http://example.com" it works fine.

Comment: Sorry didn't get. Only when you type `http://example.com` then it is a problem but `http://example.com/` is NOT a problem?

Comment: @anubhava No, there is no problem when i trype "http://example.com or https://example.com" problem is when i just type "example.com" and when it converts that to "https://example.com". Hope i am explaining it right?

Comment: No, it is not clear what is working and what is not as you are not enclosing your URLs in reverse ticks i.e. \` There is a `help` link on bottom-right for formatting help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123264/discussion-between-noviceme-and-anubhava).